# How do I find the equilibrium of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits

In the attached problem I'm given a differential equation and tasked with finding the equilibrium solution. I've tried to solve the differential equation then use the initial condition and solve for C and then taking the limit as t approaches infinity. I get large numbers like 1000 but the answer should be small(around or below 100), I know conceptually, I'm doing something wrong. I would really appreciate any help you can offer.

[The problem I'm trying to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ8Ch.png)

Comment: At an equilibrium you will have ${dy \over dt} = 0$.

Comment: That's what I was originally thinking, y would either equal 0 or 2600. I don't know what to do from there though.

Comment: You might want to read the question a little more carefully. The question is a little ambiguous in my mind.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was overthinking it. I was supposed to solve it with the initial condition, then plug in t=1 and then subtract the initial value from the t=1 value

Comment: I suspect that is the desired answer. But that would presume that all the fish were harvested at the last instant.  One could imagine a different approach where a few fish were harvested more frequently :-). Sort of a zig zag approach rather than a big drop at the end.